# VS2010 Web Installer Project not recognizing IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, installation, iis-express

I built an installer for a ASP.net web application and installing from Visual Studio fails to recognize IIS Express as a version of IIS. Is this expected behavior? If so is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes... It's expected behavior, but Visual Studio 2010 SP1 recognizes IIS Express and you can use it instead of Cassini(Visual Studio Development Server).
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2010/12/11/visual-studio-2010-sp1-beta-iis-express-integration.aspx